# Modify gradle 'classpath' variable with Build Variants

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Is it possible to modify the classpath variable with Build Variants?
Example:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
       ***classpath*** 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
   }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   mavenLocal()
}

android {
   compileSdkVersion 19
   buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

   defaultConfig {
      minSdkVersion 14
      targetSdkVersion 19
   }
   productFlavors {
      flavor1 {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
         minSdkVersion 14
         targetSdkVersion 19
      }
      flavor2 {
         classpath 'com.amazon.device.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
         minSdkVersion 17
         targetSdkVersion 17
      }
   }
}
```

I want too be able to use a different classpath in my buildscripts dependencies, but I assumed the product flavors depeneded on the buildscript to run, which seems circular and hence my question of whether I can actually modify it with product flavors. (There was no mention in the android gradle plugin examples if you could or not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-phone/docs/setup#Using%20the%20Android%20Gradle%20Plugin) the Amazon version of the Android Gradle Plugin just extends the standard plugin by adding additional support for compiling XML with SDK addon resources. To date, the corresponding Amazon version of the plugin has been released shortly after the release of the regular Android plugin. So you should have no problem with using the Amazon plugin for both your Amazon and non-Amazon builds since it is fully compatible.

Comment: I would have to hesitantly agree with you. It might be a current extension of the standard plugin for now, but Amazon is also currently 3 API versions behind the standard Android. So I wonder for how long it will be a current extension until it starts to fall behind. And it doesn't seem like the best practice when trying to design for multiple flavors to just use Amazons gradle version. Hopefully once the Fire phone gets more established this question will get revisited.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to, but you'll have to modify the project object.  The `buildscript` closure is delegated to the `Project` object for this build.gradle file.  Try changing your flavors to be:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        project.buildscript.classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    flavor2 {
        project.buildscript.classpath 'com.amazon.device.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought that would have worked too! Unfortunately I got this error:
2014-07-16 11:22:08,299 [69244706]   WARN - .project.GradleProjectImporter - 
 
2014-07-16 11:22:08,299 [69244706]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectImporter - No signature of method:
 org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.classpath() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [com.amazon.device.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+]

Comment: Ah, I think I see what is happening.  The classpath used to pick up the Android Gradle plugin is set in the buildscript block, but with the change I suggested and you're trying to accomplish, we're trying to change it from within the android closure itself.  That's really unfortunate that Amazon's toolchain can't support the core Android gradle toolchain.

Comment: Agreed @Larry! Unfortunately I don't think its possible to change the buildscript block after the fact based on flavors?
I think I'll have just have to make a separate project.